# Comparing swift Type values in unit tests - XCTAssertEqual vs ==

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, equatable

I'm trying to compare swift Type values in my unit tests and noticed that XCTAssertEqual fails to compile whereas comparing with == compiles fine.

`XCTAssertEqual(MyStruct.self, MyStruct.self)` --> Fails to compile with error "Global function 'XCTAssertEqual(*:*:_:file:line:)' requires that 'MyStruct.Type' conform to 'Equatable'"

`XCTAssertTrue(MyStruct.self == MyStruct.self)` --> Compiles fine

I would like to understand what is the difference between these two comparisons.

Comment: Isn't the error message clear enough already? `MyStruct.Type` does not conform to `Equatable`, and `XCTAssertEqual` requires its arguments to conform to that protocol.

Comment: @Sweeper Shouldn't == also fail in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`XCTAssertEqual` requires that its arguments conform to `Equatable`. `MyStruct.Type` is a meta type, which, like all meta types, does not conform to `Equatable`, so `MyStruct.self` cannot be used as an argument to `XCTAssertEqual`.

However, the `==` operator is defined for all meta types. This is why you can use `==` on them. This is a "special case" implemented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541152).

"But isn't `==` one of the requirements of the requirements of `Equatable`?" you might say. Yes, but that doesn't mean types who implements `==` automatically conform to `Equatable`. The converse is true though: every type that conforms to `Equatable` must implement `==`.